# how to remove row selection highlight from ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have two angular ui-grids in one html page but I would like to remove row selection highlighting from one of them. How can I accomplish this? I tried removing the 'ui-grid-row-selected' class in ui-grid-unstable.js but then that removes the highlight for the other grid as well which I do not want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ui-grid-selection attribute from the html and make enableRowSelection  : false on the second grid. Those two will make sure selection is disabled on the rows.

Comment: I have a column for the row selection checkmarks with enableRowHeaderSelection set to true. Doing this removes that column. I was trying to use that feature for non-selection purposes but now that it's not working out as expected, I decided to implement a custom checkbox column instead. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class with specific ID for the grid you want to remove highlighting.

```
 #gridStyle .ui-grid-row.ui-grid-row-selected > [ui-grid-row] .ui-grid-cell {
     background-color: #c9dde1; // Change to normal background-color to remove highlighting
 }
```